# firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough?

Tags: firewalld

I added some rules to my firewall using firewall-cmd --direct and when I check them they are in my iptables (for example forward_direct chain) but they do not work the same as when I add them in my normal forward chain.
I searched and find passthrough option but what does really firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough do ???

Comment: Please put your full command and output in here.

Comment: Dear @P.Goli I find the reason why they do not work properly. It's because main chains are checked first and after that other chains are checked. for example, for filter table at first main forward chain is checked and if the packet is not dropped in that you can have your forward rule in "forward_direct" chain. In my case the packets were rejected in main "forward" chain and it was not reached to the destination host... But I still do not know about --direct --passthrough option & it'll be much appreciated if you can help me about that